# How to select key in Vue multiselect and preselect option? Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

How to send key in vue multiselect plugin?
Check my code:

```
<multiselect v-model="form.docTypeIds" :options="docTypes" :multiple="true" placeholder="All" track-by="l" label="l"></multiselect>
```

docTypes is array like:

```
{
    "k": 19,
    "l": "test1"
}, {
    "k": 53,
    "l": "test2"
},
```

Right now i send object like this:

```
{
    k: 19,
    l: "testtest"
}, {
    k: 53,
    l: "testteste2"
}
```

I need to send only k and 19, 53

I need to send this:

```
[19,53]
```

Also i need to send if noting is selected i need to send

```
-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `v-model`, use `value` and `@change`

```
:value="form.docTypeIds"
```

And a `@change` hander:

```
@select="handleMultiSelection"
```

Then add the method that `reduces` the values into an `array of ids`:

```
handleMultiSelection (values) {
  this.form.docTypeIds = values.reduce((carry, obj) => {
    return obj.k
  }, [])
}
```

Comment: @ohgodwht now select option no work. 
I select a value from the dropdown but nothing happens

Comment: @developerfromBerlin It's silly, but they've chosen `@select` instead of `@change` for the event. Give it a whirl now.

Comment: Again no work. I am try and with @input. When I select any item noting happenes

Comment: Probably because this is two way binding....and bind value in input ? I don't know

Comment: Your are probably ready Action dispatcher in docs... Me to but i need to show selected items..

Comment: When i return v-model now show me selected item in input type..

Comment: Folks, this is why you should always dogfood your own components. In almost every concievable use-case for select you DONT send the text value of the drop down but the value value. Why this isn't supported is baffling and I can only conclude the devs just didn't test it in real world scenarios. Gah....